# Extend time duration for displaying "PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR" error in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

When a site receives high traffic, the tab in Mozilla Firefox stops loading and displays this error message "`PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`" as shown in screen shot.

[image: Connection reset error]

What I want is, the tab should continuously keep loading until it receives the response from the site's server without displaying this error or I want to increase the duration(time or number) for which it keeps trying to connect to that site's server by default.

I don't know whether it is possible or not but what I tried is, I changed some of the configurations from `about:config`. I increased `network.http.keep-alive.timeout` from 120 to 215 and `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server` from 6 to 20. But I don't find any noticeable change.

Are there better possibilities for achieving my expectations ?

Note: I approximately make 30-40 requests to same url(www.example.com) from different tabs with different sessions.